# Mobile Connect Contact Key with Connected Salesforce Org?

Tags: mobileconnect, marketing-cloud-connect, sms

I'm standing up MC with a connected Service Cloud org acting as the customer record. The Salesforce ContactID is the subscriber key in Marketing Cloud.

What is the best practice for establishing MobileConnect contacts? Should the same ContactID being used as the subscriber key be used to establish the Contact Key?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to keep the same Contact Key in MobileStudio as the Subscriber Key is in Email Studio.

This way you can use the same Contact in Journey Builder and Automation Studio.

So in your case, if the ContactID is used, then the same attribute should be used in MobileConnect as well.